# Marshal map[string] interface{} but with tags

Tags: json, go

I know Go has a way to `json.Marshal` struct and also `json.Marshal` `map[string]interface{}`.

But when it marshals a `struct`, it can uses its json tags'. Is there a way, in standard or with another library to `json.Marshal` a `map[string]interface{}` and to pass it the same options that would have been stored in a field tag for a `struct`?

Comment: No, you cannot.

Comment: Directly, there isn't a way. But if you really really want it, you can create an anonymous struct and pass it to `json.Marshal`.

Comment: The requirement you ask for is not needed. A map has arbitrary keys and you just can set them to the name you want. (Or are you asking about stuff  like omitempty?)

Comment: Yup, I was thinking about omitempty, for instance.

But I found a way. Btw I undestand you guys think there is no way to do that but still I do not understand the downvotes. Anyway, I will answer it by myself

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a way, a bit tricky, but still.

You have to create a struct from `reflect` package.

You iterate over each element in your map and for each of them you create a struct field :

```
fields = append(fields, reflect.StructField{
    Name: ,
    Type: ,
    Tag: ,
})
```

You can set the tags to whatever you want, meaning you can set json values, like the omitempty one.

Then you have to create the struct itself :
`s := reflect.New(reflect.StructOf(fields))`

Then another iteration over your map will be needed, to fill the struct with values.

`s.Elem().FieldByName(name).Set(WhateverValue)`

Finally you can pass your struct to `json.Marshall(s.Interface())`.

Comment: i dont understand why i would not declare a new type, configure its tags, then copy the map to a new instance of that struct to later json encode it.

Comment: it appears to me that you complicated things

Comment: Because the struct is dynamically created, and in some case, mine at least, this is needed because at the compilation time I have no idea what the struct will look like. Or maybe I missed something and you were talking about declaring new type at execution time ?

Comment: i guess there is something i dont understand. If the type is created at runtime, how do you know its tag ? What would prevent you from renaming map keys instead ?